# Missing "Site Pages" Library

Tags: site, library, restore, pages

Here's the issue I've had presented to me today. A user possibly deleted the "Site Pages" library by accident. When navigating to the site http://url.sitepages/home.aspx it returned a 404. Even attempting to navigate to the http://url.sitepages/ returned a 404. Upon looking up All Site Content, the "Site Pages" was not displayed; all of which lead me to believe the library itself was deleted. Somehow now the Site Pages library is showing, but there are not pages within. I've checked the recycling bin at site and site collection level and did not find anything. Any ideas on this? I just don't understand how it could be deleted but not appear anyway in order to restore. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This feature must be active "Wiki Page Home Page" feature to have the sitepages enabled.

http://sanketinfo.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-enable-site-pages-document.html

Site-Level feature comes when Pages and other style library is not present and also if you want to customize the look and feel of the site in site setting page.

**If you need them, you have a few options:**

Activate the “Wiki Page Home Page” feature. The feature will create
those libraries and will also create a wiki page and set it as the
home (welcome) page for your site.

If you only need the libraries and don’t want your home page changed,
you can have SharePoint Designer 2010 create the libraries for you:
Open SharePoint Designer.

In the “Site Objects” pane on the left, click “Site Pages.” SP Designer will load the contents of the Site Pages library and tell you it’s empty.

However, it also creates the Site Pages library for you in the process.
Do the same thing for “Site Assets” (also in the Site Objects pane). If you have code that depends on the existence of these libraries
(such as a feature receiver),

you can use two methods on the `SPListCollection`

*class to ensure the libraries are there:*

> EnsureSitePagesLibrary()
>
> EnsureSiteAssetsLibrary()

Comment: Works for 2013 as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has deleted anything in the site, it will be in recycle bin. But if the file is removed from the recycle bin, then it will be stored anywhere.

If you are looking for default pages from the "site pages" library, then it is not a problem. You  can get it from the another site/ site collection "site pages" library which is using the same site definition.